# How to get a dataframe with averaged individual values from multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, average

I have a dictionary with 10 dataframes:

```
d = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

Each of the dataframes have 20 rows and 100 columns:

```
d[1] =
```

[image]

Except the values of each dataframe are slightly different.

What I want to do is to create a new dataframe with averaged values of the individual cells from the 10 dataframes.

For example, in d1, at row 0 column 0, we have the number 5. I want to get the average of all the values at that position (row 0 column 0) from the 10 dataframes in my dictionary d and then put the averaged value in a new dataframe at row 0 column 0. And I want to continue doing this until I have a new, averaged dataframe.

Currently I'm thinking about adding the value of each position to a list and averaging that before adding it to the new dataframe, but I realized that this is very inefficient.

(pseudo-code)

```
for n, df in d.items():
    i.append(d[n][0].values[0])
i = sum(i)/10
# add i to new averaged dataframe
```

Is there an efficient way to do this? Preferably automated so that my final result is the averaged dataframe?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum the dataframes in the dictionary and then divide by the number of dictionaries:

```py
sum(df for df in d.values()) / len(d)
```

Demo with small sample data:

```py
d = { i : pd.DataFrame([random.choices([1,2,3,4,5],k=5) for _ in range(3)]) for i in range(3) }
d
```

Output:

```
{
0:    0  1  2  3  4
   0  3  4  4  3  2
   1  5  4  2  3  2
   2  3  3  4  5  2,
1:    0  1  2  3  4
   0  3  1  3  5  3
   1  4  5  2  1  1
   2  3  4  2  4  3,
2:    0  1  2  3  4
   0  4  1  3  4  4
   1  4  5  4  3  4
   2  1  4  2  2  3
}
```

```py
sum(df for df in d.values()) / len(d)
```

Output:

```
          0         1         2         3         4
0  3.333333  2.000000  3.333333  4.000000  3.000000
1  4.333333  4.666667  2.666667  2.333333  2.333333
2  2.333333  3.666667  2.666667  3.666667  2.666667
```